# Cell value will not update

Tags: excel, vba

I would be very grateful if anyone can help with this annoying problem.
I am trying to update a cell value and cannot understand why this code does not work.

I have tried various different ways of updating it, nut none of them will work.

```
    MyCellValue = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    MyCellValue = MyCellValue + ct1
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = MyCellValue
```

ct1 is a single and the actual value is 7.5, 
MyCellValue is a single,
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value is initially 0
The format of the cell is Number, two decimal places

Comment: `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value + ct1` should work fine.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your reply. This is the code I used originally, but as it failed to work, I then broke it down to the code I posted. The only thing I can think of, is something to do with the fact that when you ask for the ActiveCell.address it gives $S$11 and I am wondering if the absolute references are preventing it from working.

Comment: That should not matter - it only gives you $ if you use `Address(True, True)` (or omit any aguments)  Are you saying nothing happens when you run that code?  Do you have `On Error Resume Next` in your code?

Comment: I have a stop in front of these three lines of code. When you step through them, on processing the last line, it goes back to the stop and changes MyCellValue to 0 as if you hadn't stepped through the three lines of code. I have been using vba for over 15 years as a self employed programmer and I used to teach it at a college, but I have never come across this before, where what I consider to be correct code, just refuses to work.

Comment: What other code is running in the workbook? what triggeres this code?  If you extract those 3 lines to a standalone sub do they run as expected?  Something else is going on here.

Comment: I have found the problem related to violating the "Function can't manipulate values of other cells" rule. I had the code embedded in a function that was called by the formula in a cell. Just have to work out how to make it work now as calling a subroutine from the function still won't allow it to work. Many thanks for your help. It was your use of the word sub that made me realise the error of my ways.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True

Application.Calculate

#### Or something more specific/target, such as

Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns("A:C").Calculate

**Source:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(method)

Comment: The worksheet does calculate. It puts the result of calculations in over one hundred cells, except this one where it gives #VALUE! as the result. I have narrowed the problem down to these three lines of code that are not in the other cell calculations. When you perform the calculation by stepping through the code, it falls over on the last of the three lines of code.